# How to move multiple power query tables into one worksheet together in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Excel for MacOS. A lot of menu options I find online aren't available in MacOS, for example, in Power Query editor, apparently there is a `Close and Load to...` option but I don't have it. So I have two queries in there but each query result is, by default?, inserted into a separate Worksheet.

What I want to do is moving each table (the PQ result tables) from their own sheet into one sheet that I have named it "Summary".

When I click on `Queries and Connections...` menu/button, the only option I get is removing a query or refreshing it.

I'm using `Microsoft Excel for Mac, v16.x` - Office 365

--

[image]

Comment: If your datasets have the same columns, you could use powerquery `union` to stick them together. What is your next step in excel? You can proabbly do that in powerquery also

Comment: @Nick.Mc sticking them together is good but my main problem is that I'm still writing more queries but it automatically create the result table in a new sheet/tab. I don't want that, I want to put them in certain cell/sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Excel for Mac will probably always be behind Excel for Windows with these advanced query technologies, so, if you have a chance to emulate Windows on the Mac and run Win-Excel, I would advise you to do that.

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to append several queries into one, you can do that inside Power Query and load only the final query into a worksheet. All contributing queries can be set to be "Connection only", so they don't get loaded into a worksheet. -- But this command is in the "load to" dialog, which is not available in Excel for Mac.

Here is a good and current write-up of the features and limitations of Power Query in Excel for Mac, and it specifically points to the fact that all queries will be loaded into worksheets.

https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/excel-for-mac-power-query-features-and-limitations

Comment: That's annoying! What about the cloud version? Is there a way to do that in Office cloud?

Comment: I think in Excel for web you can currently only refresh queries, but not create them from scratch.